# Match NOT in Tinkerpop traversal

Tags: java, cypher, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'd like to match all `b1`, where no node `b2` exists as depicted below. 
[image]
This is some kind of a 2-hop asymmetry. Note that the *non-existent* `b2` must link to the same `c:C` as `b1`, so other `(a2) --> (b3) --> (a1)` can be ignored as long as `b3` has no edge to `c:C`.

I tried the following...

```
graph.traversal().V()
    .match(
        as("c").hasLabel("C"),

        as("a").hasLabel("A")
        .out().hasLabel("B").as("b1")
        .where(out().as("c"))
        .out().hasLabel("A").as("a2"),

        not(
        as("a2")
        .out().hasLabel("B").as("b2")
        .where(out().as("c")
        .out().as("a1")
    )
)
```

...but second MATCH step throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided match pattern is unsolvable: [[MatchStartStep(a1), HasStep([~label.eq(A)]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(B)]), WhereTraversalStep([WhereStartStep, VertexStep(OUT,vertex), WhereEndStep(c)])@[b1], VertexStep(OUT,vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(A)]), MatchEndStep(a2)], [MatchStartStep(a2), HasStep([~label.eq(B)]), WhereTraversalStep([NotStep([WhereStartStep, VertexStep(OUT,edge)])]), WhereTraversalStep([WhereStartStep, VertexStep(OUT,vertex)@[c], VertexStep(OUT,vertex), WhereEndStep(a1)])@[b2], MatchEndStep, MatchEndStep]]
```

I can't even match this is Cypher, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddenly, I found a solution which avoids scope problems:

```
graph.traversal().V()
    as("a").hasLabel("A")
    .out().hasLabel("B").as("b1")
    .where(out().hasLabel("C"))
    .out().hasLabel("A").as("a2")
    .where(
        not(
            out().hasLabel("B")
                .where(out().hasLabel("C"))
                .out().as("a")
        )
    )
```